# $\forall f$ bounded Borel functions $\exists \{f_n\}$ continuous s.t $\forall \mu$ regular Borel measures $\int f_n d\mu \to \int f d\mu$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded Borel function.

Is it true that there is a sequence $\{f_n\} \subset C(X)$ s.t for any regular Borel measure $\int f_n d\mu \to \int f d\mu$?

If so, can you provide a reference, or a proof? Is it possible to show this with tools no more advanced than the Riesz Representation theorem?

I need this to complete my proof suggested here:

[Spectral Theorem - $AB = BA \implies B\Phi(f) = \Phi(f)B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466162/spectral-theorem-ab-ba-implies-b-phif-phifb)

Comment: There is a NET s.t. $\int f_\lambda d\mu\to \int f d\mu \forall $ regular Borel measure $\mu$, not sequence.

Comment: @C.Ding I see. If you'd like, check out the linked post in the question. I'm looking for an elementary proof that those operators commute. I think the proof I gave there is correct with your statement (but unfortunately I don't have the tools to formalise a proof of the existence of this net). Maybe you'll have an idea.

Comment: @C.Ding will appreciate if you have some input for my new answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466162/spectral-theorem-ab-ba-implies-b-phif-phifb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such sequence in general. By taking Dirac delta measures we see that $f_n\to f$ pointwise everywhere. So $f$ must be of [Baire class 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1). But the Dirichlet function $1_{[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q}$ is not of Baire class 1 because it has no points of continuity.

Comment: Nice one.$\,\,\,$