# Reflexive spaces for $\ell^\infty$ and $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis

I knew that the dual space of $\ell^1$, a separable space is not reflexive because its dual space is $\ell^\infty$, which is not separable. But, I do not know whether $\ell^\infty$ is reflexive or not because I was unable to use the result on the relation between separability and reflexivity to prove it. Is there any hint on this?

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152343/a-banach-space-is-reflexive-if-and-only-if-its-dual-is-reflexive answer your question?

Comment: I guess you mean to say that $\ell^1$ is NOT reflexive, and you are asking whether $\ell^\infty$ is?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. Sorry.